# jquery effects not visible in php if "echo" is used for output

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

im having small image gallery that uses fancybox. So on each image there is a hover and popup effect. Below is my code

```
<div class="one-third column hover">
               <a href="large/28crowview_ld.jpg" class="image-box">
                <div class="photo">
                <span class="text"><span class="anchor"></span></span>
                </div>          
                <img src="large/28crowview_ld.jpg" height="170px" width="260px"/>       
        </a>                        
    </div>
```

the above code works perfectly.

but im using a ajax controller that returns the above code using an echo

```
   echo '<div class="one-third column hover">
                   <a href="large/28crowview_ld.jpg" class="image-box">
                    <div class="photo">
                    <span class="text"><span class="anchor"></span></span>
                    </div>          
                    <img src="large/28crowview_ld.jpg" height="170px" width="260px"/>       
            </a>                        
        </div>';
```

but when i use the echo tag the images are displayed but non of the hover effects are visible. it was very odd. and i also noticed the same issue on my social bar.

It works perfectly when i use it in a html view. But when i echo, i see the code in the source but the icons are not visible

```
echo '<div class="supersocialshare" data-networks="facebook,google,twitter,linkedin,pinterest" data-url="'.$share.'" data-orientation="line"></div>';
```

all the images are placed correctly, no js conflicts.

Below is the java script im using

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    var track_click = 0; //track user click on "load more" button, righ now it is 0 click

    var total_pages = <?php echo $total_pages; ?>;
    $('#results').load("<?php echo base_url() ?>fetch_pages", {'page':track_click}, function() {track_click++;}); //initial data to load

    $(".load_more").click(function (e) { //user clicks on button

        $(this).hide(); //hide load more button on click
        $('.animation_image').show(); //show loading image

        if(track_click <= total_pages) //make sure user clicks are still less than total pages
        {
            //post page number and load returned data into result element
            $.post('<?php echo base_url() ?>fetch_pages',{'page': track_click}, function(data) {

                $(".load_more").show(); //bring back load more button

                $("#results").append(data); //append data received from server

                //scroll page to button element
                $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $("#load_more_button").offset().top}, 500);

                //hide loading image
                $('.animation_image').hide(); //hide loading image once data is received

                track_click++; //user click increment on load button

            }).fail(function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { 
                alert(thrownError); //alert any HTTP error
                $(".load_more").show(); //bring back load more button
                $('.animation_image').hide(); //hide loading image once data is received
            });


            if(track_click >= total_pages-1)
            {
                //reached end of the page yet? disable load button
                $(".load_more").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            }
         }

        });
});
</script>
```

inside fetch_pages

```
    $page_number = filter_var($this->input->post('page'), FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);

        //throw HTTP error if page number is not valid
        if(!is_numeric($page_number)){
            header('HTTP/1.1 500 Invalid page number!');
            exit();
        }

        $item_per_page = 5;

        //get current starting point of records
        $position = ($page_number * $item_per_page);

        $cottages = $this->properties->getstuff($sub_location,$position, $item_per_page);

       foreach ($props as $cots):

                 echo'<div class="container section" id="'.$cots["id"].'">
                        <div class="one-third column hover">
                        <a href="'.$cots["image_url"].'" class="image-box">
                                <div class="photo">
                                    <span class="text"><span class="anchor"></span></span>
                                </div>          
                                 <img src="'.$cots["image_url"].'" height="170px" width="260px"/>

                                </a>                        

                        </div>';
 endforeach;
```

Im building this project using codeigniter, php and jquery. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It looks like the css file implementing the hover effect is not included in the 2nd case.

Comment: On success of ajax call, try to initialize the fancybox. You might be initializing on document ready when the element is not present.

Comment: @Adder can u explain it a little more?

Comment: There are no events bound as soon as you insert new elements into the DOM. You have to let fancy box set (reassign) the events to the elements inserted

Comment: Your browser does not care whether the HTML code he eventually receives comes from a static file, was dynamically created by a script – or sewn together be your grandma. So for problems like this, please compare the output of your script with the static version first (you can do that before even asking).

Comment: @Deepu added more codes

Comment: @anpsmn managed to get the popup work after re initializing. But the hover thing doesn't work yet.

Comment: @LiveEn Cool. I don't see a hover code anywhere above. Can you paste the hover code for us?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have some serious problems understanding the overall architecture of a web application, what is happening on the browser of your client and what is happening on the server, what php does, and so on. You should read up on that.

However, your problem is most likely related to the fact that your hover and popup effects are being accomplished by something equivalent to this:

```
$(".hover").on("hover",function () {
  // BLAH
});
```

If this is the case, then any elements with class hover loaded after the event handler has been attached (that is, through ajax) will not have that event handler attached to them, a simple fix would be to attach the event handler to the container and use a delegated event handler, something like this:

```
$(document).on("hover",".hover",function () {
  // This handler is attached to the document but applies to any .hover elements inside it
});
```

Another fix would be to run whatever function attaches your "fancybox" functionality to an element after the element has been loaded through ajax. Hard to get it right without some reference code but i assume it would be something like:

```
$.get(url, function (data) {
  var elem = $(data);
  $("#container").append(elem);
  elem.fancybox();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

please provide you JavaScript code, I would like to throw my cent. I bet you are using `hover` method instead of `live hover` or `on hover` functions
just like the following :

```
jQuery('#div').click(...); // this will work fine if you place your code in page not posted back from ajax request or dynamically created
jQuery('#div').live('click',...); // this will work even if the element was created dynamically or from ajax request.
```

[jQuery "live" link](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

[jQuery "On" link](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

---

one more thing, be careful the `live` function is deprecated and removed from jQuery 1.9

Answer (score 0):

According to `anpsmn` comment i had to re initialize the complete fancybox plugin within

```
$(window).load(function() {
```

it worked perfectly..